# Node.js : How to make spawn function synchronous instead of using spawnSync?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm currently using spawnSync and stdio:inherit to get the logs printed on my console. However I'm looking for custom logging to a separate file, in case if anything fails during the spawn.

I'm looking to create a wrapper around

> spawn

so that it has following properties :

- Synchronous function where output is stored in a variable
- View output on the console
- Write stdout and stderr to a file

For instance :

```
const result = spawnSync('ls', [ '-l', '-a' ], { stdio: 'inherit'}); // will print as it's processing
console.log(result.stdout); // will print null

const result = spawnSync('ls', [ '-l', '-a' ], { encoding: 'utf-8' }); // won't print anything
console.log(result.stdout); // will print ls results only on completion
```

I need `result` such that it will print while it's processing and write to a file at the same time

Also I'm looking for some strategy or solution from node.js side apart from shell scripting

Comment: If you want a synchronous result, you must use `spawnSync` not `spawn`.

Comment: I don't get what you're looking for. Do you want to write the output into a variable, a file, and stdout at the same time?

Comment: Yes. I'm looking for something that can do all the 3 functions

Comment: Then you'll need to [tee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_(command)) the stream. I'm not certain whether that is possible synchronously.

Comment: @Bergi - But, there is no such thing as a synchronous stream?  I'm thoroughly confused by this question myself.

Comment: If you don't mind it being asynchronous, this problem becomes a lot easier. I'm not sure that it's possible synchronously.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Thanks for the comment but if I want to make it asynchronous I have to make huge architectural design change in my project. So I'm looking for some wrappers which can help me to make this possible

Comment: @BipinKumarRachaputi not necessarily. You could write it asynchronously in a separate module file and then `spawnSync(process.execPath, ...)` your asynchronous module. Not terribly efficient, but you'll be able to implement your straightforward asynchronous code as a synchronous function.

Comment: Not an answer: this reminds me of https://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2015/02/01/what-color-is-your-function/ Node is a language that will require "coloring" your other calling functions.

Answer (score 0):

I guess we can't make all three possible because of the limitation of node.js

As per the documentation[image]

If we are trying to use stdio:'inherit' , we can either redirect output to parent stdout stream or file using

> fs.openSync()

Because of the limitation, we can't use custom streams too.